# TclTk image width always returns zero

Tags: image, tcl, width, tk-toolkit

Linux Debian Jessie

I have created a photo image in TclTk. Once created I want to query the the actual width so I can use it. Where I use the constant 500 in the MWE it is less obvious in the actual program.

```
% puts $tcl_version
8.6
% package require Tk
8.6.2
% set i [image create photo p0 -width 500]
p0
% #not correct
% image width p0
0
% #correct
% p0 cget -width
500
```

From the image manual page:

> **image width** *name*
>
> Returns a decimal string giving the width of image *name* in pixels.

So I would expect

```
image width p0
```

to also return the decimal value for the width. The `cget` command does return what I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It needs to have an image to have a width (pixels). Currently your image is empty.

Comment: Why does p0 cget -width return the correct width? It is the same image

Comment: @Jerry with aheight of 1 as per the answer below the correct width is returned. But it does not make sense that one function call returns a value while the other does not.

Comment: `$im cget -width` returns what you've _configured_, but `image width $im` returns the _real_ width which can be different. In your case, you've got zero _area_ so the photo image type optimizes and says there's nothing to display.

Comment: This again sheds some light on why one command returns something different than the other. Not returning the real width was exactly what happened. Which caused an undesired effect when configuring the image. Using tclmuPDF saveImage method. I could easily solve it by either calculating and  setting the image width AND height. Or omit either setting and instruct tclmuPDF to store an image with the desired size. You just have to know it.

Comment: @Donal Fellows The manual even says that about cget: the call returns what was configured. This should be read as "what was in the configuration command". Regardless whether the configuration succeeded. The difference in text is subtle, the difference in meaning is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set i [image create photo p0 -width 500 -height 1]
```

Apparently an image with an invalid height does not have a width.

Comment: Indeed with a height of 1 the correct width is returned. But why the difference between the two calls?

Comment: @HansLinkels `cget` returns what is configured, and `image width` returns the image's width.

Comment: The key thing there is that it is impossible to configure things that are, on the face of it at least, incompatible with each other. The image type has to resolve this (e.g., by precedence rules saying what to ignore). In addition, an image can have a width without one ever being configured. But all images definitely have a real width though; it's part of their basic definition.